# Showing data and posted values separately in ajax post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i have a task which is about ajax post data and also ask the script to show data...I have 3 files.. HTML file perform an ajax to the php script, passwrapper.php and then include the another script to show all data in the json format on the console.log in the html file.. I implemented some ajax post values such as 'Abdullahlahlahlah' and 'Muslim' so that the passwrapper.php will receive those data and echo on the console separatley from the whole data... Developer said ajax cannot echo 2 times...... Is it totally impossible???? If there is no way, please tell me other options...
Requirement: Please do not modify the student.php as i want the that php script to echo all the data in json..
Modify the paswrapper.php and html file..

When i run the html file, the error states

```
Status Code: 200

ErrorThrown: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1634

jqXHR.responseText:

[{"student_id":"1","student_name":"Ashfur","student_gender":"F","student_age":"19","student_religion":"Muslim","student_course_id":"1"},{"student_id":"2","student_name":"Irfan","student_gender":"M","student_age":"17","student_religion":"Islam","student_course_id":"4"},{"student_id":"3","student_name":"Alice","student_gender":"F","student_age":"21","student_religion":"Chinese","student_course_id":"2"},{"student_id":"4","student_name":"Mohit","student_gender":"M","student_age":"20","student_religion":"Christian","student_course_id":"6"},{"student_id":"5","student_name":"Susy","student_gender":"F","student_age":"27","student_religion":"Chirstian","student_course_id":"5"},{"student_id":"6","student_name":"Ida","student_gender":"F","student_age":"23","student_religion":"Islam","student_course_id":"3"},{"student_id":"7","student_name":"Abdul","student_gender":"M","student_age":"22","student_religion":"Islam","student_course_id":"1"},{"student_id":"8","student_name":"Ernest","student_gender":"M","student_age":"25","student_religion":"Chinese","student_course_id":"4"},{"student_id":"9","student_name":"Wei Ling","student_gender":"F","student_age":"23","student_religion":"Chinese","student_course_id":"2"},{"student_id":"10","student_name":"Ashtae","student_gender":"M","student_age":"23","student_religion":"Islam","student_course_id":"4"},{"student_id":"11","student_name":"Jasmine","student_gender":"F","student_age":"23","student_religion":"Chinese","student_course_id":"2"},{"student_id":"65656","student_name":"yyyyty","student_gender":"F","student_age":"65","student_religion":"anything","student_course_id":"009090"}]

Also there is the posted values on the console.log which states LastRowname = Abdullahlahlahlah LastRowReligion = Muslim
```

HTML File

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Cesium-1.34/ThirdParty/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<div id="results"</div>
<div id="resulte"</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
showData();
function showData()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "passwrapper.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            lastName: 'Abdullahlahlahlah',
            lastReligion: 'Muslim',
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('An error occurred... Look at the console (F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I, Console tab) for more information!');
            $('#resulte').html('<p>Status Code: '+jqXHR.status+'</p><p>ErrorThrown: ' + errorThrown + '</p><p>jqXHR.responseText:</p><div>'+jqXHR.responseText + '</div>');
            console.log('jqXHR:');
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log('textStatus:');
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log('errorThrown:');
            console.log(errorThrown);
        },

    });
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

passwrapper.php

```
<?php
include 'student.php';
executePass();
receivePost();
function receivePost()
{
    if ((!isset($_POST["lastName"])) and (!isset($_POST["lastReligion"])))
    {
        //do nothing
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo '<script>console.log("LastRowname = '.$_POST["lastName"].' LastRowReligion = '.$_POST["lastReligion"].'");</script>'; 
    }
}
?>
```

student.php

```
<?php
function executePass()
{

    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','netwitness') or die ("Could not connect database");
    $db = mysqli_select_db($conn,'abdpractice') or die ('Could not select database');

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from student");
    $json_array = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $json_array[] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($json_array);
}
?>
```

in my network tab

```
[{"student_id":"1","student_name":"Ashfur","student_gender":"F","student_age":"19","student_religion":"Muslim","student_course_id":"1"},{"student_id":"2","student_name":"Irfan","student_gender":"M","student_age":"17","student_religion":"Islam","student_course_id":"4"},{"student_id":"3","student_name":"Alice","student_gender":"F","student_age":"21","student_religion":"Chinese","student_course_id":"2"},{"student_id":"4","student_name":"Mohit","student_gender":"M","student_age":"20","student_religion":"Christian","student_course_id":"6"},{"student_id":"5","student_name":"Susy","student_gender":"F","student_age":"27","student_religion":"Chirstian","student_course_id":"5"},{"student_id":"6","student_name":"Ida","student_gender":"F","student_age":"23","student_religion":"Islam","student_course_id":"3"},{"student_id":"7","student_name":"Abdul","student_gender":"M","student_age":"22","student_religion":"Islam","student_course_id":"1"},{"student_id":"8","student_name":"Ernest","student_gender":"M","student_age":"25","student_religion":"Chinese","student_course_id":"4"},{"student_id":"9","student_name":"Wei Ling","student_gender":"F","student_age":"23","student_religion":"Chinese","student_course_id":"2"},{"student_id":"10","student_name":"Ashtae","student_gender":"M","student_age":"23","student_religion":"Islam","student_course_id":"4"},{"student_id":"11","student_name":"Jasmine","student_gender":"F","student_age":"23","student_religion":"Chinese","student_course_id":"2"},{"student_id":"65656","student_name":"yyyyty","student_gender":"F","student_age":"65","student_religion":"anything","student_course_id":"009090"}]<script>console.log("LastRowname = Abdullahlahlahlah LastRowReligion = Muslim");</script>
```

my requirement:
i want to echo all the data(except the posted values) on the html file.
i want to show the posted values on the console.log. it can either be in the passwrapper.php or html file..... Please help me....

Comment: It has been some time since I have used `if` conditions within `php` but shouldn't your `and` operator be `&&`? also why do you have two elements with the same `id`? `ID`'s should be unique, not sure if that's a copy/paste error...

Comment: @NewToJS, hi well both of them are the same, even I run the file, there is error which is shown above....

Comment: Is there any solutions???

Comment: I understand that, I'm just trying to understand your logic behind the way you have things set out, for example the echo returning the script tag and `console.log()`, have you tried removing that and return something else for the sake of debugging? maybe something json... Your *"Unexpected token `<` in JSON"* could be the start of the `<`script> tag you have in your echo....

Comment: @NewToJS, in the passwrapper.php, i change the echo script console to return $_POST['lastName']; the error states "Unexpected end of JSON input"

Comment: @NewToJS, is it possible to implement $.post in the ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ajax cannot echo 2 times;
1.student.php

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{

    $json_array[] = $row;
}
//echo json_encode($json_array);
return $json_array;
```

2.passwrapper.php

```
<?php

include 'student.php';

$data['student_arr']=executePass();
$data['post_str']=receivePost();
echo json_encode($data);
function receivePost()
{
    if ((!isset($_POST["lastName"])) and (!isset($_POST["lastReligion"])))
    {
        //do nothing
    }
    else
    {
        $post_str= 'LastRowname = '.$_POST["lastName"].' LastRowReligion = '.$_POST["lastReligion"].'';
        return $post_str;
    }
}
?>
```

3.html file

```
success: function(data){
   console.log(data.post_str);
   $('#results').text(JSON.stringify(data.student_arr));
},
```

Comment: I know that ajax cant echo 2 times.... Is there any other way if u did not return the json_array and instead echo the json_encode json_array...... Is it possible to echo the posted values on the passwrapper.php script rather than the html file???

Comment: If i echo the json_encode json_array, will you be able to capture the output from that function and combine to the posted values and then separate in the html file???????????????

Comment: user   mode like 'data.post_str' ;

Comment: the code which you have provided me is good. Is it possible to change the return json_array to echo json_encode(json_array) and then decode the json in the passwrapper.php and then combine it ????

Comment: can not change student.php  ?

Comment: I mean I want to echo the result and then caputre the output buffering from that php and decode the result and combine the result with the posted values and encode it.

Comment: I add another answer

Comment: OMG!!!!! I updated my code with urs. It works .. Wow You are really a genius..... Thank you. I am struggling for days....... By the way  what is the difference between ob_get_content and file_put_content as i used file_put_content and that does not work..

Comment: $('#results').text(JSON.stringify(data.student_arr)); About this code, what is the "text" for and JSON.stringify convert a javascript value to a string

Answer (score 0):

passwapper.php

```
<?php
include 'student.php';

ob_start();
executePass();
$string = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$data['student_arr']=json_decode($string);
$data['post_str']=receivePost();
echo json_encode($data);
function receivePost()
{
    if ((!isset($_POST["lastName"])) and (!isset($_POST["lastReligion"])))
    {
        //do nothing
    }
    else
    {
        $post_str= 'LastRowname = '.$_POST["lastName"].' LastRowReligion = '.$_POST["lastReligion"].'';
        return $post_str;
    }
}
?>
```